# Modified Composite Quadrature formula

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I'm trying to produce a modified composite trapezoid quadrature formula for $\int_a^b f(x)\ dx$ based on the Euler-MacLaurin formula.

I know that it should involve $f'(a), f'(b), f'''(a)$ and $f'''(b)$, but I really don't know how to put it together. Also, I think it has an error on the order of $h^6$, but I'm having a hard time seeing the math.

Comment: So you are only allowed to use those four? What about $f(a)$ and $f(b)$?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, should definitely be able to use those. I'm just having a hard time seeing how the Euler formula can be applied to the composite trapezoid quadrature to produce a new formula.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite approach to these sorts of formulas is to note that integration is linear, and so on polynomials, this amounts to a little linear algebra. There are six variables: $f^{(n)}(a):=a_n$ and $f^{(n)}(b):=b_n$ for $n\in\{0,1,3\}$. Thus we can expect to be able to find the first six terms of the power series, and so we should be able to integrate any fifth-order polynomial exactly. So now let's apply our formula to an arbitrary such polynomial:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^5c_nx^n$$

For convenience, we'll set $a=0$, $b=1$ in the integral to simplify our equations. The integral of $f$ is $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^5\frac{c_n}{n+1}$, and the derivatives of $f$ are $a_n=c_nn!$ for $n\in\{0,1,3\}$ and

$$b_0=\sum_{n=0}^5c_n\qquad b_1=\sum_{n=1}^5nc_n\qquad b_3=6c_3+24c_4+60c_5.$$

This is a linear system of six equations relating $c_n$ to $a_n,b_n$. Solving them yields:

$$c_0=a_0\qquad c_1=a_1\qquad c_2=-\frac52a_0-\frac74a_1-\frac{a_3}{16}+\frac52b_0-\frac34b_1+\frac{b_3}{48}$$
$$c_3=\frac{a_3}6\qquad c_4=\frac52a_0+\frac54a_1-\frac7{48}a_3+\frac54b_1-\frac52b_0-\frac{b_3}{16}$$
$$c_5=-a_0-\frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{a_3}{24}+b_0-\frac{b_1}{2}+\frac{b_3}{24}$$

and plugging them into the formula for the integral of $f$ (and substituting back the definitions of $a_n,b_n$) gives

$$\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=\frac{f(1)+f(0)}{2}-\frac{f'(1)-f'(0)}{12}+\frac{f'''(1)-f'''(0)}{720}$$

which is our final formula. If we are taking a general integral over $[a,b]$ instead of $[0,1]$, we can "stretch" the formula by scaling by $b-a$ horizontally. This will increase the integral by $b-a$, divide the first derivative by $b-a$, and divide the third derivative by $(b-a)^3$, so:

$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\frac{f(b)+f(a)}{2}(b-a)-\frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{12}(b-a)^2+\frac{f'''(b)-f'''(a)}{720}(b-a)^4$$

and the error term is $\int_a^b\sum_{n=6}^\infty c_nx^n\,dx=O((b-a)^6)$.

---

It is asked how this all relates to the Euler-Maclaurin formula, which is in this context

$$\sum_{n=0}^1f(n)=\int_0^1f(x)\,dx+\frac{f(1)+f(0)}2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)}(1)-f^{(2k-1)}(0)\right).$$

Truncating the sum at $k=2$ yields:

$$\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=\frac{f(1)+f(0)}2-\frac{B_2}{2!}(f'(1)-f'(0))-\frac{B_4}{4!}(f'''(1)-f'''(0)),$$

which coincides with our earlier formula because $\dfrac{B_2}{2!}=\dfrac{1/6}{2}=\dfrac1{12}$ and $\dfrac{B_4}{4!}=\dfrac{-1/30}{24}=\dfrac1{720}$.

Comment: This all looks very good! I was able to get the first part. My question, how is this based on the Euler-MacLaurin formula?

Comment: @Neurax I edited the question to respond to this. Note that I am assuming that $h=b-a$, that is, the entire integral is estimated with one subdivision. You would use this to get a more accurate estimate by applying this formula to each subdivision, although that would require you to know the derivatives at the subdivision points; alternatively you could apply Euler-Maclaurin with more terms in the sum than just $0,1$ like was used here.

Comment: Okay. I do agree that your edit supports your argument for equality. The question, as presented to me, is "Based on the Euler-MacLaurin formula, find a formula for the composite trapezoid quadrature for $\int_a^b f(x)\ dx$. While I mostly understand your logic, I'm struggling to conform this information into my argument.

Comment: @Neurax Most of the work is my general method for solving this type of problem in terms of any combination of derivatives evaluated at any points. With your particular setup, this turns out to be a special case of the Euler-Maclaurin formula, so the part after the divider is a much simpler derivation of the same result as all the linear algebra before. If you are struggling with the transformation from $[0,1]\to[a,b]$, the more precise explanation is that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_0^1g(u)\,du$, where $g(u)=f((b-a)u+a)(b-a)$. Taking derivatives on this gives the claimed powers of $b-a$.